# How to set custom cursor position of UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

When user clicks on UITextFiled the cursor is at starting point, for design purpose its not look good. So, I want to change postion of cursor +5 or from center of UITextField.

**I had implemented this code found from Github, Stil its not working. Please help me if you can guide me how to solve this problem.**

My code is below

```
#import "UITextField+Selection.h"

@implementation UITextField (Selection)

- (NSRange)selectedRange
{
    UITextPosition* beginning = self.beginningOfDocument;
    UITextRange* selectedRange = self.selectedTextRange;
    UITextPosition* selectionStart = selectedRange.start;
    UITextPosition* selectionEnd = selectedRange.end;
    NSInteger location = [self offsetFromPosition:beginning toPosition:selectionStart];
    NSInteger length = [self offsetFromPosition:selectionStart toPosition:selectionEnd];
    return NSMakeRange(location, length);
}
- (void)setSelectedRange:(NSRange)range
{
    UITextPosition* beginning = self.beginningOfDocument;
    UITextPosition* startPosition = [self positionFromPosition:beginning offset:range.location];
    UITextPosition* endPosition = [self positionFromPosition:beginning offset:range.location + range.length];
    UITextRange* selectionRange = [self textRangeFromPosition:startPosition toPosition:endPosition];
    [self setSelectedTextRange:selectionRange];
}

#import "UITextField+Selection.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   [self.nameTextField setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(5,0)]; // Category method called
}
@end
```

Comment: How does the code above behave??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of moving the cursor you can add padding to the left of the UITextFiled like this for design to look better

```
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
textField.leftView = paddingView;
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have custom position of cursor when user selects `UITextField` you need to register for notification that is posted when user selects `UITextField`.

So you can add yourself as observer (for example in `viewDidLoad` method) via:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldSelected) name:UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification object:nil];
```

And then in `textFieldSelected` method you can:

```
- (void)textFieldSelected {
    [self.nameTextField setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(5,0)];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For designing purpose, You can put Image behind UITextview, and put textview above UIImage view. It will look good for design